# Find the largest value and the smallest value of expression: $P=a+2b+2c.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization

> Let real numbers $ a, b, c$ satisfy $\left\{ \begin{align}
>   & {{a}^{2}}+{{b}^{2}}+{{c}^{2}}\le 25 \\ 
>  & 2a+b-2c\ge 12 \\ 
> \end{align} \right.$ . Find the largest value and the smallest value of expression: $$P=a+2b+2c.$$

I solved the problem as below:
$$\left\{ \begin{align}
  & {{a}^{2}}+{{b}^{2}}+{{c}^{2}}\le 25 \\ 
 & 2a+b-2c\ge 12 \\ 
\end{align} \right.\Rightarrow {{a}^{2}}+{{b}^{2}}+{{c}^{2}}-2a-b+2c-13\le 0 
(1)$$ 
$$P=a+2b+2c\Leftrightarrow a+2b+2c-P=0 (2) $$ 
 $(1)$ corresponding sphere with center $I\left( 1;\frac{1}{2};-1 \right)$ and radius $$R=\frac{\sqrt{61}}{2}$$
$(2)$ corresponds to the plane $$\left( \alpha  \right):a+2b+2c-P=0$$
The problem of finding conditions of plane and sphere with common intersection. This happens when: $$d\left( I,\left( \alpha  \right) \right)=R\Leftrightarrow \frac{\left| -P \right|}{3}\le \frac{\sqrt{61}}{2}\Leftrightarrow -\frac{\sqrt{61}}{2}\le P\le \frac{\sqrt{61}}{2}$$
So $$\min P=-\frac{\sqrt{61}}{2},\max P=\frac{\sqrt{61}}{2}$$
Please comment and give better solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you do after the words "this happens when".  You should be be looking for the values of P so the the plane is tangent to the sphere.

Comment: Please check: 1) $a = \frac{11}{3}, b = \frac{10}{3}, c = -\frac{2}{3}$, 
$a^2+b^2+c^2 = 25$, $2a+b-2c = 12$, but $a+2b+2c = 9$.
2) $a = \frac{5}{3}, b = -\frac{2}{3}, c = -\frac{14}{3}$,
$a^2+b^2+c^2 = 25$, $2a+b-2c = 12$, but $a+2b+2c = -9$.